# How can I disable Azure webjob storage queue processing for specific queue items?

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs, azure-webjobssdk, azure-queues

I've got a queue-triggered Azure webjob function:

```
public void ProcessQueueMessage([QueueTrigger("%MyQueue%")] Item item, TextWriter logger)
    {
       // Do normal processing...
    }
```

I want to selectively ignore certain queue items based on a condition.  For example if I'm out of Widget X and I don't want to keep processing widget shipments until I have stock.  So I want to ignore/skip all Widget X queue items temporarily.  So something like:

```
public void ProcessQueueMessage([QueueTrigger("%MyQueue%")] Item item, TextWriter logger)
{
    if (!HaveStock(WidgetX))
       // Ignore queue item - treat it as if it was not in the queue at all

    // Do normal processing...
}
```

Throwing an exception to fail processing doesn't seem like an option to me because it'll poison the message.

I could set the VisibilityTimeout to some arbitrarily high value and then throw an exception but then when I wanted to perform the processing (as opposed to just waiting for the timeout) I'd have to have a separate process scan for queue items with the higher VisibilityTimeout and set the timeout to a lower value (not even sure if this is possible).  But making a process to scan those queue items is what I'm trying to avoid in the first place as I'd like to keep the logic in the queue-triggered function if possible.

What options do I have?

Update: I recognize that what I'm trying to accomplish is inconsistent with the purpose of queue-triggered functions in the first place given that the reason for queue-triggered events is to do something when a message appears, and that if I want selective processing I could implement a queue-polling and message handling process myself.  But I'm trying to take advantage of the higher level of abstraction that triggered processing provides.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would like to say; Let Queue be Queue, and let FIFO be FIFO.

If you want to handle *conditional message processing* with queue, I suggest two options.

**1. Use Azure Service Bus Topics**

For selective FIFO filter, replacing Azure Queue with Azure Service Bus Topic can be a candidate.

See the tutorial to get a hint:
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/websites-dotnet-webjobs-sdk-service-bus/#topics

**2. Use secondary Queue**

Similar to poisoned-queue, send ignored one to secondary Queue and process them later in another logic. I recommend this as we can understand flows easily.

```
CloudQueueClient queueClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudQueueClient();
_secondaryQueue= queueClient.GetQueueReference(storageQueueName);
_secondaryQueue.CreateIfNotExists();

public static void ProcessQueueMessage([QueueTrigger("%MyQueue%")] Item item, TextWriter logger)
{
    // send to secondary queue.
    await _secondaryQueue.AddMessageAsync(new CloudQueueMessage(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(item)));
}
```

Comment: You've helped me realize that indeed I'm breaking the semantics of a queue triggered function.  If I was starting over I'd take your suggestion #1 (or even if I still used queues rather than service bus I'd still do my own polling).  I like your idea #2.  But if I use the native queue output binding that means *every* input queue item will be saved to the output queue (the `out` parm *must* be set).  So rather than using an output queue binding I'm simply saving the messages that meet my criteria to the 2nd queue.

Comment: @Howiecamp // You are right. I editted second answer.